# Algoritmo de LRU c++, ¿Cómo puedo poner los fallos de página abajo de los números?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int c=0;
char b[5][20];

int lru(char p[],int f,int n){
int i=0,j=0,k=0,m,l=0,flag1=0,flag2=0,pf=0,index=0;
char fr[f],fs[f];

for(i=0;i<f;i++){
    fr[i]='-';
}

c=0;

for(i=0;i<f;i++){
    for(j=0;j<20;j++){
    b[i][j]='\0';
    }
}

for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    flag1=0;flag2=0;
        for(i=0;i<f;i++){
        if(fr[i]==p[j]){
            flag1=1;
            flag2=1;
        for(m=0;m<f;m++){
            b[m][c]=fr[m];
        }
        c++;
        break;
    }   
}

    if(flag1==0){
        cout<<"F\n";
        for(i=0;i<f;i++){
            if(fr[i]=='-'){
            pf++;
            fr[i]=p[j];
            flag2=1;
            for(i=0;i<f;i++){
            b[i][c]=fr[i];
            }
        c++;
        break;
        }
        }
    }
    if(flag2==0){
    for(i=0;i<f;i++)
    fs[i]=0;
        for(k=j-1,l=1;l<=f-1;l++,k--){
            for(i=0;i<f;i++){
            if(fr[i]==p[k])
            fs[i]=1;
            }
        }
   for(i=0;i<f;i++){
    if(fs[i]==0)
     index=i;
   }
   fr[index]=p[j];
   pf++;
   for(i=0;i<f;i++){
    b[i][c]=fr[i];
    }
    c++;
    }
    }

 return pf;
}



int main(){
    int n,frame,fault2,i=0,j=0,k=0,count=0;

    cout<<"Introduce numero de paginas:";
    cin>>n;
    char p[n];
    cout<<"\nIntroduce las paginas:";   
        cout<<"\n";
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>p[i];
        }
    cout<<"\nIntroduce numero de marcos:"<<endl;
    cin>>frame;
    cout<<"\n";

    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Least Recently Used:";
    fault2=lru(p,frame,n);


    for(i=0;i<frame;i++){
    j=0;
    cout<<"\n";

    while(b[i][j]!='\0'){
    cout<<b[i][j];
    cout<<" ";
    j++;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    }

    cout<<"\n\n\n";
    cout<<"The Page Fault in LRU is:"<<fault2<<endl;
    return 0;
```

}[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Hace dos años atrás cuando cursaba Sistemas Operativos, yo implementé diferentes algoritmos de cambios de páginas, entre ellos LRU. Puedes hechar un visita a mi página: http://www.germix.tk/2017/01/14/page-replacement/

Te dejo una versión en C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0
typedef int bool;

struct page
{
    char key;
    struct page* next;
    struct frame* frame;
};
struct page_list
{
    struct page* head;
    struct page* tail;
};
struct frame
{
    struct page* page;
};
struct frame_list
{
    int count;
    struct frame* frames;
};
struct result_info
{
    struct page** pages;
    bool* faults;
    int faults_count;
};
//
// Buscar página
//
struct page* page_list_find(const struct page_list* list, char key)
{
    struct page* p = list->head;
    for(p = list->head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    {
        if(p->key == key)
            return p;
    }
    return NULL;
}
//
// Crear la lista de todas las páginas
//
void page_list_init(struct page_list* list, const char* seq)
{
    int i;

    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(seq); i++)
    {
        struct page* p = page_list_find(list, seq[i]);
        if(!p)
        {
            p = (struct page*)malloc(sizeof(struct page));
            p->key = seq[i];
            p->next = NULL;
            p->frame = NULL;
            if(list->head == NULL)
            {
                list->head = p;
                list->tail = p;
            }
            else
            {
                list->tail->next = p;
                list->tail = p;
            }
        }
    }
}
//
// Borrar de la memoria la lista de páginas
//
void page_list_clear(struct page_list* list)
{
    struct page* p;
    struct page* n;
    for(p = list->head; p != NULL; p = n)
    {
        n = p->next;
        free(p);
    }
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
}
//
// Crear lista de marcos
//
void frame_list_init(struct frame_list* list, int count)
{
    list->count = count;
    list->frames = (struct frame*)malloc(sizeof(struct frame) * count);
    memset(list->frames, 0, sizeof(struct frame) * count);
}
//
// Borrar de la memoria la lista de marcos
//
void frame_list_clear(struct frame_list* list)
{
    free(list->frames);
    list->frames = NULL;
}
//
// Crear la lista de faltas
//
void result_info_init(struct result_info* info, int frames_count, int sequence_length)
{
    info->pages = (struct page**)calloc(frames_count*sequence_length, sizeof(struct page*));
    info->faults = (bool*)calloc(sequence_length, sizeof(bool));
    info->faults_count = 0;

    memset(info->pages, 0, frames_count*sequence_length*sizeof(struct page*));
    memset(info->faults, 0, sequence_length*sizeof(bool));
}
//
// Borrar de la memoria los resultados
//
void result_info_clear(struct result_info* info)
{
    free(info->pages);
    free(info->faults);
}
//
// Algoritmo LRU
//
void lru(const char* sequence, const struct page_list* page_list, const struct frame_list* frame_list, struct result_info* result_info)
{
    int i;
    int frn = 0;
    int sequence_length = strlen(sequence);

    for(i = 0; i < sequence_length; i++)
    {
        int j;
        char key = sequence[i];
        struct page* page = page_list_find(page_list, key);
        struct frame* frame = NULL;

        if(i > 0)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < frame_list->count; j++)
            {
                result_info->pages[(j*sequence_length)+i] = result_info->pages[(j*sequence_length)+(i-1)];
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < frame_list->count; j++)
        {
            if(frame_list->frames[j].page == page)
            {
                frame = &frame_list->frames[j];
                break;
            }
        }
        if(frame == NULL)
        {
            frame = &frame_list->frames[frn];
            result_info->pages[(frn*sequence_length)+i] = page;
            if(++frn == frame_list->count)
                frn = 0;
            frame->page = page;
            result_info->faults[i] = true;
            result_info->faults_count++;
        }
    }
}
void main()
{
    char* sequence = "332215431121";        // Secuencia de páginas
    int frames_count = 3;                   // Cantidad de marcos
    int sequence_length = strlen(sequence);
    struct page_list page_list;
    struct frame_list frame_list;
    struct result_info result_info;

    //
    // Crear listas
    //
    page_list_init(&page_list, sequence);
    frame_list_init(&frame_list, frames_count);
    result_info_init(&result_info, frames_count, sequence_length);

    // Ejecutar algoritmo LRU (Least Recently Used)
    lru(sequence, &page_list, &frame_list, &result_info);

    printf("Marcos: %d\n", frames_count);
    printf("Secuencia: %s\n", sequence);
    {
        int i;
        int j;

        printf("%c", 201);
        for(i = 0; i < sequence_length-1; i++)
            printf("%c%c", 205, 203);
        printf("%c%c\n", 205, 187);
        for(j = 0; j < frames_count; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", 186);
            for(i = 0; i < sequence_length; i++)
            {
                struct page* p = result_info.pages[(j*sequence_length)+i];
                if(!p)
                    printf(" %c", 186);
                else
                    printf("%c%c", p->key, 186);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        // ...
        printf("%c", 204);
        for(i = 0; i < sequence_length-1; i++)
            printf("%c%c", 205, 206);
        printf("%c%c\n", 205, 185);
        // ...
        printf("%c", 186);
        for(i = 0; i < sequence_length; i++)
        {
            if(result_info.faults[i])
                printf("%c%c", 'X', 186);
            else
                printf("%c%c", ' ', 186);
        }
        printf("\n");

        // ...
        printf("%c", 200);
        for(i = 0; i < sequence_length-1; i++)
            printf("%c%c", 205, 202);
        printf("%c%c\n", 205, 188);
    }
    printf("Cantidad de fallos de pagina: %d\n", result_info.faults_count);
    //
    // Borrar todo
    //
    page_list_clear(&page_list);
    frame_list_clear(&frame_list);
    result_info_clear(&result_info);
}
```

Este código me da el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]